# Finding most valuable paths

Tags: r, machine-learning, graphical-model, graph-theory, path-model

I am trying to analyze a data set of user journeys. My data looks as follows

```
user week1 week2 week3 week4 spend
1    A, B  B,E   F, G  A     10
2    B     F     G     H     15
...............................
1000 C     G     A     F     20
```

I would like to determine the most valuable paths (highest spend), and the frequency of those paths to determine the most frequent paths. What are the best types of models to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear why you would need a model to compute the frequencies of the "paths" in your dataset (whatever those might be) or identify the rows with the highest values of "spend."  Could you explain?

Comment: Maybe a 'methodology' is a better question. I would like to be able to say at the end, most users take this journey, or users who take that journey spend on average $X dollars